# iReport merge same field into one field by using conditions

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to merge two field if they have the exact value into one field?
I want to use conditions to print the field when it have the same value as of another field.

Here is an example of my iReport:
[image]

say that this field have the exact value
[image]

how can I merge these two fields into one field whenever they have the exact value.

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: It is possible. For text fields, `name-type2` and `launched3`, provide `print when expression` as `$F{name_type1} != $F{name_type2} || $F{launched2} != $F{launched3}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent repeating data in JasperReports TextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202593/how-to-prevent-repeating-data-in-jasperreports-textfield) & [Issue with repeating values in iReport/JasperReports 3.6.1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9354352/876298)

Comment: doesnt work how can I achieve this using conditional expressions?

Comment: `doesnt work how can I achieve this using conditional expressions?` - What code does not work?